# Sharepoint site collection

Tags: sharepoint, office365

Is it possible to add sites under one site collection in SharePoint online like this

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/IT
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/IT/Asia
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/IT/America
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you could create a site collection first: https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/IT.

After you create the site collection, you could create two subsites under the site https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/IT.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change name at **/sites** ?? for eg :use https:company.sharepoint.com/IT/abc instead of https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/IT.

Comment: Currently this cannot be done in SharePoint Online. You could vote this in UserVoice: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330318-sharepoint-administration/suggestions/18967900-create-managed-paths-in-sharepoint-online

Answer (score -1):

Go to your site collection `https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/IT`.

Click Site contents and then Subsites or this link `https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/IT/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx?view=15`.

Create two new Subsites with Asia and America url